# How to add/remove class to selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I am trying to add a class that changed the border color of the selectize.js to red but I am unable to achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
if(!coborrowerid){
    document.getElementById("coborrowerid").classList.add("form-validation-error");
}
else{
    document.getElementById("coborrowerid").classList.remove("form-validation-error");
}
```

I am adding my own form validation error class when there is no selected item.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, my suggestion is to check if your element ID is correct `coborrowerid`

Comment: @LocMai are you using selectize.js? It is working on a normal select tag but when using selectize.js its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether your `coborrowerid` ID is correct. You can try something like 
 `coborrowerid = document.getElementById("find-me");` just to make sure.